# Can you duplicate someone else's Minehut Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minehut

My friend and I have been playing on my other friend's minecraft server for quite a while. We have a really pretty house that we're proud of and netherite gear. The server has gotten super toxic recently and we won't stop getting harassed. The only reason we haven't quit is because we've made so much progress that we don't want to lose. We thought maybe we could create a duplicate of the minecraft server that we can play on and we can invite nicer people to play with us.

Is there any way to duplicate my friend's minecraft server? The server is a minehut server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist tools called "[world downloader](https://www.google.com/search?q=minecraft%20world%20downloader)". As you explore the world these will save the chunks locally so they can be loaded into a new world. It seems there are variants both as client mods and as seperate tools that sit between client and server.

There are some caveats though, first that areas you do not explore will not be saved. Secondly I believe chest contents are only stored on the server side so they can't be saved unless you open them.

The other option would be to ask the servers admin nicely if they will provide all or part of the data files.

You will also probably want the world seed so that newly generated chunks line up with your downloaded chunks, again you can either ask the admin nicely or there are tools to [reverse engineer](https://www.google.com/search?q=minecraft+seed+reverse+engineer) the seed.

Disclaimer: I have not used these tools myself and cannot vouch for thier safety or which version/fork of them are best (hence why I have linked the google search instead of any particular fork) it may also piss off the admin of the server.